# Azure: a Service Bus that distributes to all subscribers of a single subscription

Tags: azure, events, azureservicebus

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I need to distribute messages to all nodes in a cluster. All those nodes will subscribe to an event based on a name, but would not be able to disambiguate in any other way. That is, I can't have individual subscriptions set up for each node because it's dynamic - nodes come and go.

Azure's Service Bus (topics) does not seem appropriate for this because for multiple subscribers using the same subscription name, it will deliver in a round-robin fashion.

Is there anything in Azure that will allow me to publish an event and have all current subscribers *to the same "subscription"* receive it?

Comment: I think you might have confused service bus with Azure Storage queues. With Service Bus, If a dozen consumers subscribe to a topic, they'll each get a message you publish to the topic (depending on filtering rules)

Comment: @DavidMakogon each of those consumers would need their own subscription though. I won't be able to have a subscription per consumer because I'd have to dynamically create (and destroy) subscriptions via code. I will have many consumers subscribed to the same _subscription_, which will round-robin the events. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest spending time with Service Bus docs? I'm not sure how to respond, because... the way a single message is sent to multiple destinations is through subscriptions to a topic. This is how any message broker works: service bus, Rabbit MQ, Amazon's SNS... You don't subscribe to a subscription; you subscribe to a *topic*. Someone publishes a message on a topic, and anyone who's subscribed... gets a copy of the message. That's pretty much it.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm starting to wonder if we're talking about the same thing. I have spent time with both the docs and code AND I'm observing the round-robin behavior I speak of. You say subscriptions are to topics, but take a look at [the constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.subscriptionclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet) for `SubscriptionClient`. They all take a `subscriptionName`, and that's what I mean by "I can't have individual subscriptions". All nodes would be connected to the same subscription name, so round-robin occurs.

Comment: And here it is, straight from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions) (emphasis mine): _Among other things, this feature means that **subscriptions** support the same patterns described earlier in this section with regard to queues: **competing consumer**, temporal decoupling, load leveling, and load balancing._

Comment: If "nodes come and go" how would you detect that a message is no longer needed?

Comment: @spodget if I follow your question, there's no need to detect that. A message is delivered to active subscribers. If there are no susbcribers, the message isn't delivered to any one. If a node is down, it misses the message.

Comment: @me-- did you find solution to your problem ? I'm facing this right now as well !